Can someone help me with moving average logic in Pine Script?
I'm facing an issue with a Pine Script strategy I've been working on, and I'd appreciate your help.
Strategy Overview:
Entry condition: the strategy enters a trade when the price crosses above (for a long) or below (for a short) a simple moving average (MA).
Exit conditions:
Take Profit (TP): Set in pips (e.g., 1,000 pips for a $10 move).
Stop Loss (SL): Also set in pips (e.g., 100 pips for a $1 move).
Trade Direction: There's an input option to choose between long positions, short positions, or both.
The Issue:
The TP and SL levels are functioning correctly. Trades exit at the specified profit or loss levels when those price points are reached.
However, the problem arises when the price crosses back over the moving average before reaching the TP or SL levels. The strategy exits the trade immediately upon this crossover, even though I want the trade to stay open until the TP or SL is hit.
What I've observed:
For example, if I enter a long trade when the price crosses above the MA and set a TP of 1,000 pips and an SL of 100 pips:
If the price moves in my favor and reaches the TP, the trade closes with a $10 profit as expected.
If the price moves against me and reaches the SL, the trade closes with a $1 loss as expected.
But if the price crosses back below the MA before hitting either the TP or SL, the trade closes immediately. This is not the behavior I want.
//@version=5
strategy("MA Strategy with SL/TP", 
         overlay=true, 
         margin_long=100, 
         margin_short=100, 
         initial_capital=10000, 
         process_orders_on_close=true, 
         pyramiding=1)

//==========================================================
//------------------- Inputs -------------------------------
//==========================================================

// Moving Average Inputs
maLength = input.int(50, title="MA Length", minval=1)
maType   = input.string("SMA", title="Moving Average Type", options=["SMA", "EMA", "WMA", "RMA", "HMA", "VWMA"])

// Trade Direction Input
tradeDirection = input.string("Both", title="Trade Direction", options=["Long", "Short", "Both"])

// Stop Loss / Take Profit Enable Inputs
useSL = input.bool(true, title="Use Stop Loss?")
useTP = input.bool(true, title="Use Take Profit?")

// Stop Loss / Take Profit Mode (Percent, Pips, Dollars)
slTpMode = input.string("Percent", title="SL/TP Mode", options=["Percent", "Pips", "Dollars"])

// Take Profit / Stop Loss Values (TP first, then SL below)
tpValue = input.float(2.0, title="Take Profit Value", step=0.1)
slValue = input.float(1.0, title="Stop Loss Value", step=0.1)

//==========================================================
//------------------- Utility Functions --------------------
//==========================================================

// Function to get the selected moving average
getMA(maType, src, length) =>
    ma = switch maType
        "SMA"  => ta.sma(src, length)
        "EMA"  => ta.ema(src, length)
        "WMA"  => ta.wma(src, length)
        "RMA"  => ta.rma(src, length)
        "HMA"  => ta.hma(src, length)
        "VWMA" => ta.vwma(src, length)
    ma

// Convert SL/TP values to appropriate price levels for Long positions
convertSLTP(entryPrice) =>
    float stopPrice = na
    float limitPrice = na
    if slTpMode == "Percent"
        stopPrice  := entryPrice * (1 - slValue / 100)
        limitPrice := entryPrice * (1 + tpValue / 100)
    else if slTpMode == "Pips"
        pip = syminfo.mintick
        stopPrice  := entryPrice - slValue * pip
        limitPrice := entryPrice + tpValue * pip
    else if slTpMode == "Dollars"
        stopPrice  := entryPrice - slValue
        limitPrice := entryPrice + tpValue
    [stopPrice, limitPrice]

// Convert SL/TP values to appropriate price levels for Short positions
convertSLTPShort(entryPrice) =>
    float stopPriceShort = na
    float limitPriceShort = na
    if slTpMode == "Percent"
        stopPriceShort  := entryPrice * (1 + slValue / 100)
        limitPriceShort := entryPrice * (1 - tpValue / 100)
    else if slTpMode == "Pips"
        pip = syminfo.mintick
        stopPriceShort  := entryPrice + slValue * pip
        limitPriceShort := entryPrice - tpValue * pip
    else if slTpMode == "Dollars"
        stopPriceShort  := entryPrice + slValue
        limitPriceShort := entryPrice - tpValue
    [stopPriceShort, limitPriceShort]

//==========================================================
//------------------- Strategy Logic -----------------------
//==========================================================

// Calculate the Moving Average based on user selection
ma = getMA(maType, close, maLength)

// Plot the Moving Average for visualization
plot(ma, title="Moving Average", color=color.blue)

// Conditions for entries
longEntry  = ta.crossover(close, ma)
shortEntry = ta.crossunder(close, ma)

// Decide which trades to allow based on user input
enterLong  = (tradeDirection == "Long" or tradeDirection == "Both") and longEntry
enterShort = (tradeDirection == "Short" or tradeDirection == "Both") and shortEntry

// Declare variables for exit levels (initialized to na)
var float longTP = na
var float longSL = na
var float shortTP = na
var float shortSL = na

// Handle Long Entries/Exits
if enterLong
    // Enter Long Position
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    
    // Calculate SL and TP prices
    [stopPriceLong, limitPriceLong] = convertSLTP(close)
    
    // Assign SL and TP based on user settings
    longSL  := useSL ? stopPriceLong : na
    longTP  := useTP ? limitPriceLong : na
    
    // Conditionally set exit parameters
    if useTP and useSL
        strategy.exit("Long Exit", "Long", stop=longSL, limit=longTP)
    else if useTP and not useSL
        // Only TP, no SL
        strategy.exit("Long Exit", "Long", limit=longTP)
    else if not useTP and useSL
        // Only SL, no TP
        strategy.exit("Long Exit", "Long", stop=longSL)
    // If neither TP nor SL is enabled, do not set exit condition

// Handle Short Entries/Exits
if enterShort
    // Enter Short Position
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
    
    // Calculate SL and TP prices
    [stopPriceShort, limitPriceShort] = convertSLTPShort(close)
    
    // Assign SL and TP based on user settings
    shortSL  := useSL ? stopPriceShort : na
    shortTP  := useTP ? limitPriceShort : na
    
    // Conditionally set exit parameters
    if useTP and useSL
        strategy.exit("Short Exit", "Short", stop=shortSL, limit=shortTP)
    else if useTP and not useSL
        // Only TP, no SL
        strategy.exit("Short Exit", "Short", limit=shortTP)
    else if not useTP and useSL
        // Only SL, no TP
        strategy.exit("Short Exit", "Short", stop=shortSL)
    // If neither TP nor SL is enabled, do not set exit condition

//==========================================================
//------------------- Plotting ------------------------------
//==========================================================

// Plot Long Take Profit
plot(useTP and not na(longTP) ? longTP : na, title="Long TP", color=color.green, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=2)

// Plot Long Stop Loss
plot(useSL and not na(longSL) ? longSL : na, title="Long SL", color=color.red, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=2)

// Plot Short Take Profit
plot(useTP and not na(shortTP) ? shortTP : na, title="Short TP", color=color.fuchsia, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=2)

// Plot Short Stop Loss
plot(useSL and not na(shortSL) ? shortSL : na, title="Short SL", color=color.orange, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=2)

A moving average is simply a starting position to say, Hey I want to enter a trade long or short but once that is set, the stop loss or take profit is the exit condition.

Hedging is not supported on Tradingview. When you are in a long position and you place a short order, it will close the long trade and go short.
Therefore, you need to add a check to your long and short conditions and check if you are not in a position to place your order. That way, it will only place your orders if you are not in a position already.
enterLong  = (tradeDirection == "Long" or tradeDirection == "Both") and longEntry and (strategy.position_size == 0)
enterShort = (tradeDirection == "Short" or tradeDirection == "Both") and shortEntry and (strategy.position_size == 0)

